# HowTo create ASP:Buttons in Code-Behind? (or just add an working Eventhandler to Standard-Buttons?)

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Code works perfectly with normal Buttons. But i need to add some Code-Behind to those dynamically added Buttons. Thus i'd need ASP:Buttons instead of Standard-Buttons.
How do i do this?

At the moment my working Code looks like this (only the important parts):

```
AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane nrX = new AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane();

Button b = new Button();
b.OnClick += Eventhandler(my_function);

nrX.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(b);
```

Currently the Eventhandler is not called. When i look at the produced source in the Browser, there is noch onclick Event or anything like that which is (i think) the problem.
So how can i change my "Button b" to an "ASPButton" b? Adding an attribute "runat="server"" doesn't do the trick, as this code is (of course) executed after the page_load...
Or am i getting something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing **WHEN** the button is created. if you create the button just prior to the rendering of the page, it won't have any matching when the ASP.NET tries to find the event handler associated.

If you need to create buttons dynamically, make sure that you recreate them during the page load event, so the ASP.NET has a reference to attach the event handlers.

Comment: I'm calling a method which creates those buttons in the page_load event. Adding a b.RedirectUrl does work - but i need more. So is this really the problem?

Comment: when i try b.RedirectURL Asp.net adds the Code without any Problem and creates an onclick event. So is this really the problem?